# Pry REPL with sublime text 3 does not resume after closing sublime

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, pry

I've followed the [instructions](https://github.com/pry/pry/wiki/Editor-integration) to set sublime text 3 as pry's default editor via the `~/.pryrc` file.

ST3 opens just fine when running the `edit` command in a pry session.

However, for some reason, when I close ST3, the control does not return to the running pry session's REPL. This obviously has to be unexpected behavior...

I have had the custom pry editor setting working with `vim`. However, I am trying to use ST3 in an educational environment where I can't teach with `vim`.

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to include the `-w` option to `subl`, that is:

```
Pry.config.editor = "subl -w"
```

That seems to work for me.